# Trigger Button from Modal form in table populated from loop in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am having a table populated like this from a database:

[image]

When I press the edit button, a modal with form opens with the data to edit from each person like:

[image]

How am I going to trigger the Save button from php?

My code:

```
<table style="width: 100%;" aria-describedby="example_info" role="grid" id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable no-footer" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr role="row">
                                <th aria-label="Name: activate to sort column descending" aria-sort="ascending" style="width: 256px;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="example" tabindex="0" class="sorting_asc">Name</th>
                                <th aria-label="Position: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 400px;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="example" tabindex="0" class="sorting">Surname</th>
                                <th aria-label="Office: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 197px;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="example" tabindex="0" class="sorting">Country</th>
                                <th aria-label="Salary: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 154px;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="example" tabindex="0" class="sorting">Rating</th>
                                <th aria-label="Salary: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 154px;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="example" tabindex="0" class="sorting">Date</th>
                                <th aria-label="Salary: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 154px;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="example" tabindex="0" class="sorting">Review Visible</th>
                                <th aria-label="Salary: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 154px;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="example" tabindex="0" class="sorting">Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <?php
                            while ($row = $query->fetch()) {?>

                                <tr class="odd" role="row">
                                    <td class="sorting_1"><?=$row['first_name'];?></td>
                                    <td><?=$row['last_name'];?></td>
                                    <td><?=$row['country'];?></td>
                                    <td><?=number_format($row['rating'], 2);?></td>
                                    <td><?=$row['feedback_date'];?></td>
                                    <td><?=$row['feedbackVisible'];?></td>
                                    <td><button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-id="myModalHorizontal_<?=$row['csid'];?>" data-target="#myModalHorizontal_<?=$row['csid'];?>" name="button_<?=$row['csid']?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">
                                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>&nbsp;
                                    </button></td>
                                </tr>
                                <div class="modal fade" id="myModalHorizontal_<?=$row['csid'];?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <!-- Modal Header -->
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <button type="button" class="close" 
                                                   data-dismiss="modal">
                                                       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                       <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                                                </button>
                                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                                                    Edit Feedback : <?=$row['first_name'];?>(<?=$row['country'];?>)
                                                </h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- Modal Body -->
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

                                                  <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label  class="col-sm-4 control-label">Homepage Teaser</label>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" 
                                                        id="teaser_<?=$row['csid'];?>" value="<?=$row['teaser_text'];?>"/>
                                                    </div>
                                                  </div>

                                                  <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Feedback</label>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                        <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="5" name="feedbackcomment"><?=$row['feedback'];?></textarea>
                                                    </div>
                                                  </div>

                                                  <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Feedback Comment</label>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                        <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="3" name="feedbackcomment"><?=$row['feedbackComment'];?></textarea>
                                                    </div>
                                                  </div>

                                                  <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Display Website</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                                        <input name="displayWebsite" id="checkbox-0" <? if ($row['feedbackVisible'] == 1){ echo "checked"; }?> type="checkbox">
                                                    </div>
                                                  </div>
                                                  <button type="button" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                                                </form>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- Modal Footer -->
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            <?php 
                                if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                                    console_log('Button', 'Pressed');
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

The actual part where I try to trigger is:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   console_log('Button', 'Pressed');
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by *"How am I going to trigger the Save button from php?"*. Don't you just click the save button and process the form?

Comment: when i click the button nothing happens...it should write Button: Saved to the console log but nothing happens

Comment: But the page reloads no?

Comment: the page does not reload

Comment: Do you have a javascript/jQuery that uses `preventDefault()` when clicking a button?

Comment: no but i am using DataTable js if that has to do something

Comment: That is where my expertise ends, I don't know anything about DataTable js but it sounds like there may be a `preventDefault()` happening on the form. If that is the case, then that library should have a cancellation class/feature that will ignore that submission prevention and allow the button to work normally. Not being an expert, it's hard to say. If I was in a bind and time was of the essence, I may create an event that would fire in that instance and override the default action but if the library has cancellation, then that would not be best practice.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood. You'll need to use AJAX. If you are using JQuery, see [this](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/). Example:

```
        $('form').submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.post("yourPHPpage.php", $('form').serialize(), function(data) {
                alert(data);
            });
        });
```